# Firebase Custom Auth Error: The custom token format is incorrect

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, jjwt

I am generating token using JJWT library like this -

```
    final String issuer = "my-app-auth-server@my-app-797ab.iam.gserviceaccount.com";
    final String sub = "my-app-auth-server@my-app-797ab.iam.gserviceaccount.com";
    final String aud = "https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/google.identity.identitytoolkit.v1.IdentityToolkit";
    final String secret = "my-secret-key"   //only demo key , not real secret key that i am using



    final long iat = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L; // issued at claim
    final long exp = iat + 60L; // expires claim. In this case the token expires in 60 seconds

    final String jwtString = Jwts.builder()
                .claim("alg","HS256")
                .claim("iss", issuer)
                .claim("aud",aud)
                .claim("iat", iat)
                .claim("exp", exp)
                .claim("uid",number)
                .setSubject(sub)
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, secret)
                .compact();
```

The secret key("my-secret-key") i am using is generated by Firebase , as stated [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/server/setup#add_firebase_to_your_app)

But i am getting this error when i am signing in Firebase with the token generated as above -

```
com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException: The custom token format is incorrect. Please check the documentation.
                                                                         at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzafd.zzes(Unknown Source)
                                                                         at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzafa$zzg.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                         at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzafl.zzet(Unknown Source)
                                                                         at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzafl$zza.onFailure(Unknown Source)
                                                                         at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzafg$zza.onTransact(Unknown Source)
                                                                         at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:367)
                                                                         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

This is how it looks decoded -

[image]

Please help , Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`my-secret-key` is not a valid Base64 string.  Please read the JavaDoc for the `signWith(SignatureAlgorithm, String)` method:

```
/**
 * Signs the constructed JWT using the specified algorithm with the
 * specified key, producing a JWS.
 *
 * <p>This is a convenience method: the string argument is first
 * BASE64-decoded to a byte array and this resulting byte array is 
 * used to invoke {@link #signWith(SignatureAlgorithm, byte[])}.</p>
 *
 * @param alg the JWS algorithm to use to digitally sign the JWT, 
 *            thereby producing a JWS.
 * @param base64EncodedSecretKey the BASE64-encoded algorithm-specific 
 *        signing key to use to digitally sign the JWT.
 * @return the builder for method chaining.
 */
JwtBuilder signWith(SignatureAlgorithm alg, String base64EncodedSecretKey);
```

Cryptographic signatures are always computed with byte array keys - never strings. You can get the UTF-8 bytes of a String, for example `"my-secret-key".getBytes("UTF-8");`, but that only masks what *could* be a very problematic cryptographic weakness.

Digital signature keys (again, byte arrays), should ideally never be based on simple strings like 'my secret' or 'my password'. Or, at the very least, if a simple password should be used as a signing key, it is almost always better to send it through a key-derivation algorithm (like PBKDF2) and then use that resulting output as the signature key. This ensures sufficient cryptographic entropy (randomness) that short, human-readable strings don't (and which are therefore risky).

Signing keys should ideally always be:

1. generated by a secure-random number generator or at the least created via a cryptographically secure key-derivation function and
2. and this is important - of sufficient length for the hashing algorithm to be used.

Number 2 is why JJWT provides the `MacProvider.generateKey` method - to ensure you always have keys of sufficient strength for the algorithm chosen. You can then easily base64 the result:

```
SecretKey key = MacProvider.generateKey(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256);
String base64Encoded = TextCodec.BASE64.encode(key.getEncoded());
```

This is why JJWT expects Base64 by default - because if you do these best practices, you'll always end up with a byte array key (e.g. key.getEncoded()). And if you have a byte array key, the most common way to turn that into a string (e.g. for configuration) is to Base64-encode that byte array.

Finally, note that `TextCodec.BASE64.decode(myKey)` does NOT produce the same byte array (key) as `myKey.getBytes('UTF-8')`. The latter is usually incorrect in cryptographic contexts.

That means that my-secret-token-to-change-in-production.getBytes("UTF-8") might represent a weakened signing key, and as a result, shouldn't be used. I recommend dumping that current key and generating a new one with strong cryptographic guarantees as shown above (e.g. using JJWT) and ensuring your Node library base64-decodes your string correctly.

So, once you have a secure random generated byte array and Base64 that, then check the "secret base64 encoded" checkbox in the above tool, and it should work for you.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion sir ,  actually i am not using "my-secret-key" as key for the encryption , i didn't wrote the actual key , that i am using  , here because of security  issues. The key i am using is actually created by Firebase , as stated [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/server/setup#add_firebase_to_your_app) , I should have mentioned this , my bad.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are minting tokens in Java, you can make use of the official Firebase Java SDK which has token minting built-in. Follow the instructions and code samples [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/server/create-custom-tokens#create_custom_tokens_using_the_firebase_sdk) to start creating custom tokens.

I think your main problem is that you're creating a token with HS256 encryption but Firebase requires RS256, as noted [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/server/create-custom-tokens#create_custom_tokens_using_a_third-party_jwt_library). But if you use the official library, it will handle all of this for you.

Comment: Thank you for response , the official library given  for creating tokens is Firebase server-side SDK , meaning that it is meant to be used on servers , but what i am doing is that creating tokens right inside android app ,meaning locally , and then sign in with it . (i know i am not supposed to create tokens locally but right now it suits my requirements). And on the topic of encryption algo , i think you are right about HS256 , although i have not tested it yet .

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with a PHP JWT generator library and the solution was playing with the `iat` payload parameter. My server was some seconds in the future compared to google's one (the error message never told me that...).

I just defined the `iat` payload parameter 5 minutes in the past and boom, it worked.

Hope this will help.